# How to extract the zip file using Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, unzip, epub

I am implementing EPUB reader to view epub files using Android. The epub files will be download in zip format. How can we extract the zip file in folder and get the file path of that extracted files folder in Android. I have seared the solution. But most of the codes are available in JAVA code only. Can anyone suggest on this?

Comment: did you got any solution?